# How to generate all the possible combinations for a list of elements grouped in different sizes?

Tags: python, combinations

I'm trying to create an algorithm that will return all the possible combinations from a list of elements (fruits in this example). The challenge is that the **elements can be grouped in different sizes** and **the number of elements on the result list must be equal to *n***, where *n* is the *list size*. In short, all the elements must be on the final list.

Here is an example:

`fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Watermelon']`

We can quickly find all the combinations without repetition from size 0 to *n* as follows:

```
from itertools import combinations

fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Watermelon']
for L in range(0, len(fruits) + 1):
    for subset in combinations(fruits, L):
        print(subset)
```

The result:

```
()
('Apple',)
('Orange',)
('Banana',)
('Watermelon',)
('Apple', 'Orange')
('Apple', 'Banana')
('Apple', 'Watermelon')
('Orange', 'Banana')
('Orange', 'Watermelon')
('Banana', 'Watermelon')
('Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana')
('Apple', 'Orange', 'Watermelon')
('Apple', 'Banana', 'Watermelon')
('Orange', 'Banana', 'Watermelon')
('Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Watermelon')
```

However, what I'm looking for is different because all the elements must be present. Examples:

```
('Apple',) ('Orange',) ('Banana',) ('Watermelon',) is valid (1),(1),(1),(1)
('Apple',) ('Orange',) ('Banana', 'Watermelon') is valid (1),(1),(2)
('Apple',) ('Banana',) ('Orange', 'Watermelon') is valid (1),(1),(2)
('Apple',) ('Watermelon',) ('Orange', 'Banana') is valid (1),(1),(2)
('Apple',) ('Orange', 'Banana', 'Watermelon') is valid (1),(3)
...
('Apple', 'Orange') ('Banana', 'Watermelon') is valid (2),(2)
('Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Watermelon') is valid (4)
```

Is there an easy way to generate this in Python?

Comment: So you want all of the different ways to break a list up into subgroups.

Comment: I see recursion here

Comment: Exactly, @ScottHunter! That's what I'm looking for. Maybe the best option is to use recursion as mentioned by @AverageGod, but I'm not well familiarized with Python, so I was wondering if there is a smart way of generating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the [more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) library. And more particularly to the [set_partitions](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.set_partitions) method that should suits your needs.

```
from more-itertools import set_partitions

fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Watermelon']

for itm in set_partitions(fruits)):
    print(itm)
```

The ouput produce is :

```
[['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Watermelon']]
[['Apple'], ['Orange', 'Banana', 'Watermelon']]
[['Apple', 'Orange'], ['Banana', 'Watermelon']]
[['Orange'], ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Watermelon']]
[['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'], ['Watermelon']]
[['Orange', 'Banana'], ['Apple', 'Watermelon']]
[['Apple', 'Banana'], ['Orange', 'Watermelon']]
[['Banana'], ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Watermelon']]
[['Apple'], ['Orange'], ['Banana', 'Watermelon']]
[['Apple'], ['Orange', 'Banana'], ['Watermelon']]
[['Apple'], ['Banana'], ['Orange', 'Watermelon']]
[['Apple', 'Orange'], ['Banana'], ['Watermelon']]
[['Orange'], ['Apple', 'Banana'], ['Watermelon']]
[['Orange'], ['Banana'], ['Apple', 'Watermelon']]
[['Apple'], ['Orange'], ['Banana'], ['Watermelon']]
```

### EDIT:

And if you want all every combinations possible if you reorder your orignal list you can use the previous method in combination with the the *permutations* method of **itertools** with something like:

```
import itertools
from more_itertools import set_partitions

fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Watermelon']
output = list()

for x in itertools.permutations(fruits):
    output += list(set_partitions(x))
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks much, Yannick. For the second solution, I just changed `itertools. permutations` to `itertools.combinations` because the order is indifferent in my case.